# What $_POST[] do i need to post to a forum?

Tags: php, curl, forum, bots, phpbb3

I am admin on a forum.
Earlier we had phpbb 2.0 and i made a bot that could write to the forum.
Now, we have upgraded the forum to phpbb 3.0, but i can't get my bot to write to the forum anymore.

I have looked for a solution, but now i am out of ideas. 
So it would have been great if anyone have a suggestion.

i have btw used CURL and php to make this bot.

Usage of bot:
Users log in on an external website to report results of footballmatches they have played online. The bot will then automatically write a post to the forum.

So basically i need to know what $_POST[] i need to send.

Answer (score 4):

I would advise looking at the source code of the 'add post' form on the site. Check the HTML; you will need to emulate each `input` or `select` element, as these are the POST values that are submitted via the form.

Answer (score 1):

Or get hold of a good http packet analyser (e.g. Fiddler on Windows) and look at what your browser sends when you manually post.

I agree with Toytown Mafia, though, Looking at the sending or receiving page's source should be simple enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Firefox, you can use [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) to see what's being generated with the form, and also [live http headers](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/) to see what actually gets sent back.

The HTTP headers would probably be the best way to go as it'll include cookie headers too, and you might find that phpbb 3 is checking for a user session before allowing a user to post.

If you know your way around PHP as well, you could just look through the source and see what validation it's performing (or use a step through debugger).

Answer (score 0):

Found that it is recommended to rather use the phpbb functions instead of directly editing the database. 
The topic here: http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=71&t=936535&p=5358845 shows a good example of how to get it working.
The function for posting to a forum is explained here: wiki.phpbb.com/Submit_post

Answer (score 0):

Since it's your forum, why not create a script that queries the database and does appropriate `INSERT` when it is required to post?

I personally think this would be a better idea than to post using HTTP queries... Unless it really isn't your forum...

Comment: it's my forum, and the reason why i wanted to do it that way, was because of the already existing system.